# SQL Command to execute when connecting to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wonder if i can create a database while connecting the database. I mean to say can we write SQL Command to execute when connecting to MySQL server.

I tried something like :

> mysql -u root -p[root_password] 'create database testdata;'

but it is not working for me. An help will be appreciated. I also think that it is possible as typing the `--help` i am getting this.

That is what i am getting :

```
 D:\source code\database>mysql -u root -pchangeme1
 Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
 Your MySQL connection id is 79
 Server version: 5.5.8 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

 Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

 Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
 affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
 owners.

 Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

 mysql> use testdata
 ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'testdata'
 mysql> Ctrl-C -- exit!
 Bye
```

Connects fine , no database named `testdata`. But now trying this.

```
 D:\source code\database>mysql -u root -pchangeme1 -e 'create database testdata;'
 mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.8, for Win32 (x86)
 Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

 Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
 affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
 owners.

 Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
   `enter code here`-?, --help          Display this help and exit.
   -I, --help          Synonym for -?
   --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                  'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                  and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                  --disable-auto-rehash.
                  (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
   -A, --no-auto-rehash
                  No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                  table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                  mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
   --auto-vertical-output
                  Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
                  result is wider than the terminal width.
   -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
                  (Enables --silent.)
   --character-sets-dir=name
                  Directory for character set files.
   --column-type-info  Display column type information.
   -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
                  default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
                  with --comments.
   -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.
   -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
   --debug-check       Check memory and open file usage at exit.
   -T, --debug-info    Print some debug info at exit.
   -D, --database=name Database to use.
   --default-character-set=name
                  Set the default character set.
   --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.
   -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
                  file.)
   -E, --vertical      Print the output of a query (rows) vertically.
   -f, --force         Continue even if we get an SQL error.
   -G, --named-commands
                  Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's
                  internal commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the
                  named commands can be used from any line of the query,
                  otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.
                  Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is
                  disabled by default.
   -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after function names.
   --init-command=name SQL Command to execute when connecting to MySQL server.
                  Will automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.
   --local-infile      Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.
   -b, --no-beep       Turn off beep on error.
   -h, --host=name     Connect to host.
   -H, --html          Produce HTML output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-e` if you need to execute a command in MySQL from shell.

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -e "CREATE DATABASE test_cli;"
```

Have look

```
mysql --help 
  -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
                      file.)
```

**UPDATE**

Its working for me

Login to MySQL

```
abdul@xmpp3:~/Desktop$ mysql -uroot -proot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 340
Server version: 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

Check does the database already exists

```
mysql> show databases like 'test%';
+------------------+
| Database (test%) |
+------------------+
| test_cli         |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> \q
Bye
```

As testdata doesn't exists we can create it

```
abdul@xmpp3:~/Desktop$ mysql -u root -proot -e 'create database testdata;'
abdul@xmpp3:~/Desktop$
```

No Errors , Its Working check it out again

```
abdul@xmpp3:~/Desktop$ mysql -uroot -proot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 342
Server version: 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases like 'test%';
+------------------+
| Database (test%) |
+------------------+
| test_cli         |
| testdata         |
+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i have tried this command but it is showing me all the options like if you type `mysql --help` . Not creating the database

Comment: Updated my answer with password, I hope you are not passing password or missing something else.

Comment: Yes i do understand that you mentioned only `-e option` here. for ex i am trying this command `mysql -u root -pmypass  -e 'create database testdata;' ` . But it is not crating the database rather showing me all MySQL options . Which is smiler if you type `mysql --help`.

Comment: Have a look , I have updated my answer it is working for me !

Comment: Yes a Abdul , I know it is working fine for you. But see i updated my qns not working for me .

Comment: Any idea what is the issue :(

Comment: Try using `"` as `mysql -u root -pchangeme1 -e "create database testdata;"`

Comment: thanks a lot that worked perfect `''` causing the issue should be `""`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pipes`:

```
echo "create database testdata;" | mysql --user=root -p[root_password]
```

Answer (score 1):

try the `-e` switch

```
mysql -u root -p[root_password] -e 'create database testdata;'
```